# Creating a Source out of an EventStream

Tags: scala, playframework, server-sent-events, akka-stream, reactive-streams

I am using PlayFramework 2.5.3 and would like to create an `akka.stream.scaladsl.Source` from an `akka.event.EventStream` (the eventstream is part of an actor system). The event stream would produce events from a certain type, so I would need to subscribe to that certain type of events and push them by using `play.api.mvc.Results.chunked`. Is there any easy way to create such a `Source` using Akka Streams 2.4.5?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Source.actorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.5/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source$@actorRef[T](bufferSize:Int,overflowStrategy:akka.stream.OverflowStrategy):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.actor.ActorRef]) together with the subscription. `Source.actorRef` is a source which materializes into an `ActorRef`, so you can do this:

```
// choose the buffer size of the actor source and how the actor
// will react to its overflow
val eventListenerSource = Source.actorRef[YourEventType](32, OverflowStrategy.dropHead)

// run the stream and obtain all materialized values
val (eventListener, ...) = eventListenerSource
    .viaMat(...)(Keep.left)
    <...>
    .run()

// subscribe the source actor to the stream
actorSystem.eventStream.subscribe(eventListener, classOf[YourEventType])

// now events emitted by the source will go to the actor
// and through it to the stream
```

Note that `actorRef` source is somewhat limited, for example, it naturally does not support backpressure overflow strategy for its internal buffer. You may want to use [`Source.actorPublisher`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.5/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source$@actorPublisher[T](props:akka.actor.Props):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,akka.actor.ActorRef]) with an actor which extends [`ActorPublisher[YourEventType]`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.5/index.html#akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher) trait, it will give you a bit more control. However, since `EventStream` is a pure push-based source, you won't be able to do much more with `ActorPublisher` than with `Source.actorRef`, so you may just as well use the simpler approach.

Comment: Could you please explain why one has to first call `run()` (i.e. to materialize the stream) in order to obtain a reference to the actor reference?

Comment: @Mihai238 that's because the actor reference is the `Source.actorRef`'s *materialized value*. Materialized values, as their name suggest, are values which are produced upon the stream materialization. Because `Source.actorRef` is a blueprint for the stream which can be materialized multiple times, it has to provide a separate `ActorRef` for each materialization. After all, it wouldn't be very useful if it would only provide one `ActorRef` across all materializations.